# request for member `title' in `kniga', which is of non-class type `main()::BookList[((unsigned int)((int)k))]'

Tags: types, for-loop, request, member

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
int i,k=6;       
struct BookList
{
       string title;
       string author;
       string publisher;
       int year;
};   BookList kniga[k];
```

//-----------------------------------

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
cout<<"Vavedete dannite za kniga "<<i<<endl;
cout<<"Zaglavie ";
getline(cin,kniga.title[i]);
cout<<"---------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"Avtor ";
getline(cin,kniga.author[i]);
cout<<"---------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"Izdatelstvo ";
getline(cin,kniga.publisher[i]);
cout<<"---------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"Godina ";
getline(cin,kniga.year[i]);
cout<<"---------------------"<<endl;
```

//-----------------------------------

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
cout<<"Spisak s vavedeni knigi "<<endl;
cout<<"------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"Kniga "<<i<<endl;
cout<<"Zaglave "<<kniga.title[i]<<endl;
cout<<"Avtor "<<kniga.author[i]<<endl;
cout<<"Izdatelstvo "<<kniga.publisher[i]<<endl;
cout<<"Godina "<<kniga.year[i]<<endl;
cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
```

//--------------------------------------
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
First am sorry for this question I know that it's asked many times , but I need your                       help I do something wrong and cannot find what